# Prevent SQL injection in api call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have a React project. It has a PostgreSQL database. I created the api calls. Im pretty sure the way I have it written makes it succeptable to SQL injection. How can I rewrite it that can avoid this? Keeping in mind I have tons of api calls I would have to rewrite.

```
app.post("/comment/add", function (req, res) {
  let sqlquery = `INSERT INTO dbo.comments(
  eqid,empid,comment, createddate)
  VALUES ('${req.body.eqid}', '${req.body.empid}', '${req.body.comment}',now()
 
  ) RETURNING commid`;
try{
console.log(req.body)
  pool.query(sqlquery, (err, result) => {console.log(result , err)
    if (result.rowCount) {
      res.json({eqid:result.rows[0].eqid});
    }else {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).json({ error: "Error while adding comment" });
    }
  });
}catch(error){

}
  
});
```

Comment: You avoid SQL Injection by using *parameterization* techniques.  What those techniques look like depends on which data access technology you are using.

Comment: read the docs on the lib, most likly its `pool.query(sqlquery, [req.body.eqid, req.body.empid, ...], (err, result)` and params are `?`, but it could be diff. SQL injections should be in your mind whilst developing, not as an afterthought, also you shouldn't console.log in backend code but use a logger which doesn't output to stdout

Comment: Yes im aware it should have been in mind ahead, but this project was not going to go into production, was just a project but a client is buying it from me. I need the best way to now handle the issue at hand. I'm still new to building apps so any humble help is greatly  appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Add validation to your params (req.body , req.params etc), and proceed to run query only if valid params are received.

You can build your own custom middlewares for apis that does so , or use other services for example if using express [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator)